# Any links for Twilio Video Chat - Twilio Common & Twilio Conversation Client Frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, twilio-video

I am working on Video Chat application using Twilio using Objective - C.

2 years back, we have implemented video chat using Twilio Frameworks like Twilio Conversation Client & Twilio Common Frameworks using Manual process.

While developing we have downloaded the frameworks using

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/ios

But now it is replaced with TwilioVideo framework.

So, is there any links to get latest versions of Twilio Common & Twilio Conversation client frameworks through cocoapods or from github.

I searched them in Cocoapods but not able to find it.

I referred below link

https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs/issues/80

I tried installing using cocoapods like below

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

xcodeproj 'Project'
workspace 'Project'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target :"Project" do
    platform :ios, '8.1'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.3'
    pod 'SocketRocket', '0.5'
    pod 'TwilioSDK', '~>1.2.6'
    pod 'TwilioConversationsClient', '~>0.25.1'
    pod 'TwilioCommon', '~> 0.3.4'
end
```

But it says Unknown command: `TwilioCommon` and Unknown command: `TwilioConversationsClient`

So, Is there any links for that framework latest versions or else I need to start migrate to TwilioVideo framework of Twilio? Any valuable suggestions are appreciated...!

Thanks All,

Comment: You mean, "is there any links to get latest versions of Twilio Common & Twilio Conversation client frameworks through cocoapods or from github." is your question?  Have you read Help Center > What topics can I ask about here?

Comment: @EI Tomato, I just tried installing using cocoapods, but with no luck. So I am asking anyone who has succeeded in getting latest versions of above Twilio frameworks using cocoapods or any other sources...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully installed the latest versions using cocoapods as below

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'

xcodeproj 'XXXXXXX'
workspace 'XXXXXXX'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target :"XXXXXXX" do
    platform :ios, '8.1'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.3'
    pod 'SocketRocket', '0.5'
    pod 'TwilioSDK', '~>1.2.6'
    pod 'TwilioConversationsClient'
    pod 'TwilioCommon'
end
```

Thanks,